# Getting Software caused connection abort: socket write error, while calling an API which performs file upload using Apache JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to do a performance test for an API  using JMeter tool in a GCP based VM. The API uploads 2 .xlxs files.
With all the setup, when I am calling the API in GCP based VM, I am getting

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error.

Whereas when  I am calling the same API with same configuration in my local machine I am able to get the success response: **"statusCd":"0000","statusDesc":"SUCCESS"**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried disabling the firewall, also did a network reset for the GCP VM but not able to get the desired response post these operations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure to upload the xlsx files to the same location in the GCP machine as in your local machine.

If it doesn't help:

1. Enable [Java debug logging for network connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   javax.net.debug=all
   ```
2. Enable [JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for Apache HTTP components by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```
3. Compare [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and [jmeter.log files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for local and GCP executions and you should be able to figure out what is the difference in the setup. My expectation is that you might have some local JMeter config overrides i.e. from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) JMeter Wiki page.